# How Do I Set A UISlider To A Number In A UILabel?

Tags: objective-c, uilabel, uislider

I would like to know how to set UISlider to a number in the UILabel.

What i've tried:

size = UISlider

sizetxt = UILabel

```
[size setValue:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", sizetxt]];
```

All I get is a failed build saying:

> Sending 'NSString *' to parameter to incompatible type 'float'

Any help would be appriceated.

Comment: Read `UISlider` documentation...this will 100%  help you...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Convert it to float:

```
[size setValue:[sizeTxt floatValue]];
```

Comment: Thanks for the help, it led me to looking into that code more and found the answer:

    NSString *num = sizetxt.text;
    [size setValue:[num floatValue]];
Thank you